# Hiding UIButton from GameScene

Tags: swift, uibutton, sprite-kit

I added an UIButton to my GameViewController in storyboard and set it to hidden.

Now I want to let that button show up from the GameScene

I have set the Restoration ID to "sharee" and I also set the Document label to "sharee", but when I use sharee.hidden = false in my GameViewController or GameScene, it says: "use of unresolved identifier sharee".

How can I interact with the UIButton I added in storyboard from my GameScene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you want to make a reference to the button when you assign the scene. You want to make sure you create an IBOutlet from your storyboard to your view controller as well.

In your game's view controller before you present the scene.

```
yourGameScene.button = _yourViewControllerButton;
```

Declare the button reference in your scene header.

```
@property UIButton *button;
```

Then in your implementation of the scene make the button hidden by typing...

```
_button.hidden = YES;
```

And make it appear by typing...

```
_button.hidden = NO;
```

Edit in more detail:

First you want to make sure that you have an IBOutlet connected to your view controller. The easiest way for someone starting out to do this is by switching to the assistant editor and then holding control button down and then clicking on your game button and dragging it into the interface section of the game view controller class. It will make a line. (Make sure it is the right view controller on your second view and make sure to choose outlet, not action, if it prompts.)

[image: assign ib outlet]

Secondly you want to add a property in your game scene header. You can name it whatever you want but for the tutorial sake just name it button and change it around later if you wish.

```
@property UIButton *button;
```

Third, when you created this game scene and started assigning properties, go ahead and set the view controller button reference to the game scene button reference.

[image: view controller implementation]

Finally, do whatever you want to implement the hiding and the showing. For me I made it by toggling it in the touchesBegan method.

[image: game scene implementation]
[image: off]
[image: on]

Comment: Do I exactly copy paste the code you have written?(except yourGameScene = GameScene & youViewController = GameViewController)

Comment: @sdd Well I'm not sure if you made a typo or writing shorthand but you want to assign the button not the scene or view controller to the property. So yourViewControllerButton. And yes it's verbatim except for the different named properties. Make sure you assign an IBOutlet from your storyboard to the view controller though and assign that inside the view controller class to the scene's button property you create.

Comment: SO your first line of code will be for me: sharee.button = shareButton;   ?

Comment: @sdd I'll create a project and upload some photos for you. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll be waiting

Comment: @sdd Edited with pictures. Going to spend some time with the family now. If you need help I can get to it a bit later.

Comment: 1 more question: I added the UIButton with storyboard, but later I want to change the position and size in GameScene. I tried button.frame = CGRectMake(...) but nothing happens. How can I do that?

Comment: @sdd I'm not sure of the actual method name but you use _button setImage: (new image) forState: (normal) to change a picture and I've never tried to change a button frame mid game but you could try the setImageInsets: method

Comment: @Scott  Property 'button' not found on object of type 'SKScene*'    from scene.button = myButton;    Did everything you've explained and Im getting this error.  Do you know why?

Comment: @jeff the button property isn't on the SKScene it is on the view controller overlay.